# NU1202: Package is not compatible with net50-windows

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a .NET 5 WPF application (x64) that references a user control library.
When I reference the library directly, everything works.

But when I create a Nuget package and then build the app referencing the Nuget package on my build server I get:

> NU1202: Package MyControls is not compatible with net50-windows  (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0,Profile=windows) / win-x64.
>
> Package MyControls supports:
>
> - net50-windows7.0 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0,Profile=windows7.0)
> - netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)

The MyControls .csproj file contains this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The app .csproj file contains this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
   
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I don't understand why it outputs a package for windows 7.
I found this link that describes it:
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14553
One of the comments in there seems to match my case:

> I had the same phenomenon and when I tried to install these packages
> in a .NET 5 app, it told me that "net5.0" and "net.5.0-windows7.0"
> aren't compatible. All my projects where "net5.0-windows" actually,
> though.

If I manually copy the net5.0-windows7.0 folder to a new folder net5.0-windows under .nuget/packages, the Nuget error goes away.

But instead I get this compile error:

> errorCS0103: The name 'Windows' does not exist in the current context

What should I change to make the Nuget restore work?

Comment: How did you build your package?

Comment: I used MSBuild Pack with /p:Configuration=Release /p:PlatformTarget=AnyCPU /p:Prefer32bit=False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the target framework from windows to windows 10, like so:

MyControls (Nuget package) csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

App csproj:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

After that the Restore error disappeared.

Answer (score 6):

I have tested your issue with these two csproj files and did not faced the same behavior.

So please try the following steps:

- uninstall `MyControls` nuget package on your app project first.
- then, [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`
- delete `bin` and `obj` folder of the app project.
- reinstall `MyControls` nuget package again to test it.

Comment: The error is happening on a build server where I don't normally have to clean the cache. I think it deletes the bin and obj folders on each build.

Comment: Deleting `bin` and `obj` folder is not the main point. I think your build server has some old  error nuget caches which restores on your build server. So when you builds your project, it always uses the old error one. So that is why I suggest you should clean the nuget cache first. Please delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`, and then build your project to install the latest, right version from your nuget feed.

Comment: I deleted the package folder for MyControls, after restoring, it contained (under lib) the two subfolders net5.0-windows7.0 and netcoreapp3.1

Comment: Clear nuget cache save me. idk why cache when i use local nuget (from directory)

Answer (score 1):

Increasing NuGet version to 5.X worked for me. It should be added before restore

Comment: `nuget update -self` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version of visual studio I used from 2017 to 2022, which fixed this issue for me and the solution could be build with the latest version.